# When testing with react-testing-library, do you need to test all child component functionality from a parent?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, cypress, react-testing-library

Let's say I have the following scenario:

```
const A = number => (
  <>
    <h1>A Heading!</h1>
    <B number={number} />
    <p>Some stuff after</p>
  </>
)

const B = number => (
  <ul>
    {times(number, value => <li>{value}</li>)}
  </ul>
)
```

In a framework like `enzyme` I would test component `B` by ensuring the list prints as expected.  Then I would test component `A` by ensuring that component `B` exists and received the correct `number` prop.

However, when I test with `react-testing-library` it appears that I need to test component `B` in a similar manner to the method used with `enzyme`, but then I also need to do those same tests when I test `A` (on top of `A`-specific testing).  This results in a ton of test duplication.  I suppose this is the intention, as it requires the component to be tested as a whole (including children), but this can be cumbersome.  For example, what happens when I have components `C`, `D`, and `E` (etc.).  If they are all nested I will have duplicate test cases everywhere.

It seems like I would be better off just writing a bunch of `cypress` tests for the application and ignoring `react-testing-library` entirely.  The `enzyme` method appears to provide the same coverage/confidence without all the duplication.  Can somebody help me understand this situation better?

Comment: Isn't it enough to write all of the component tests for `A`? The point is to check if the user sees the correct content. So using `A.test.js` to check if `B` is working correctly in the context of `A` is absolutely correct. I'm rather new to `react-testing-library` myself, but this seems to be the intention.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  What would happen if I wanted to use B outside of A though, in component C for instance?  Then I would need to test all of that stuff in component C as well.  Or worse yet, what if I ended up putting A and C in their own containers?  There must be a reasonable way of dealing with this scenario.  Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I personally test the individual pages of my application, i. e. everything in my `views` folder. Those are very high level tests and all are from the user's perspective. So: User clicks "Save" => Expect "Save" to disappear. No individual component tests necessary. Those tests are similar to UI tests, just without the BrowserStack subscription. So, if you put A and C in their own containers, you'll just write individual, user-guided tests for the containers instead.

Comment: Pages are rarely the same. If they do have some duplicate components, you could test for the differences between the pages. Sometimes the data in the components is different.

Comment: That is a good idea.  However, if you are going to go all the way up the tree to a page level test, why not just skip `react-testing-library` and go straight to cypress?  Wouldn't they essentially be equivalent at that point?

Comment: There's a big difference between UI tests (Cypress) and Component / Unit tests (react-testing-library). I personally like mocking things like authentication and state per test, which is hard to do in a UI testing environment.